# Automapper for inner join LINQ

Tags: c#, automapper

Currently, I have successfully use Automapper to map my hall entity to Dto as below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<HallDto>>> GetHallDto()
    {
        return await _context.Halls
            .ProjectTo<HallDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

But for another web api method below, how do I use Automapper when my I have inner join LINQ? At the moment, this is how I manually map them.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MovieHallDto>>> GetMovieHallDto()
    {
        var movieHallListDto = await (from mh in _context.MovieHalls
                             join m in _context.Movies on mh.MovieId equals m.Id
                             join h in _context.Halls on mh.HallId equals h.Id
                             select new MovieHallDto
                             {
                                 Id = mh.Id,
                                 MovieTitle = m.MovieTitle,
                                 HallNo = h.HallNo,
                                 MovieDateTime = mh.MovieDateTime
                             }).ToListAsync();

        return movieHallListDto;
    }
```

Here is my AutoMapperProfile

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Movie, MovieDto>();
        CreateMap<Hall, HallDto>();
        CreateMap<MovieHall, MovieHallDto>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your dto is really a composite of the entities. Since it doesn't appear that you can navigate from MovieHall to Movie, or to Hall, adding navigation properties to MovieHall would allow you to define the mapping. You then just select mh & call ProjectTo like you're doing with ToListAsync

Comment: `ProjectTo` is designed to work with navigation properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many joins you have to get your data from the database. It is easy to map the required properties as shown below.

In your case, I think you wanted to know how to map List. You should configure the Mapper correctly as shown below.

```
 CreateMap<MovieHallDto, MovieHall>(); //<Source, Destination>
// MovieHall class should have Id , MovieTitle ,HallNo , MovieDateTime  properties
```

Modify your output of the API.

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MovieHall>>> GetMovieHallDto()
    {
        var movieHallListDto = await (from mh in _context.MovieHalls
                             join m in _context.Movies on mh.MovieId equals m.Id
                             join h in _context.Halls on mh.HallId equals h.Id
                             select new MovieHallDto
                             {
                                 Id = mh.Id,
                                 MovieTitle = m.MovieTitle,
                                 HallNo = h.HallNo,
                                 MovieDateTime = mh.MovieDateTime
                             }).ToListAsync();

var model = Mapper.Map<List<MovieHall>>(movieHallListDto );

return Ok(model );

    }
```

If you have the tables with proper referential integrity, you can use like below.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MovieHall>>> GetMovieHallDto()
{

    var movieHalls  = _context.MovieHalls.Include(c => c.Movies).ThenInclude(c => c.Halls).ToListAsync();

    var model = Mapper.Map<List<MovieHall>>(movieHalls);

    return Ok(model);

}
```

```
CreateMap<MovieHallDto, MovieHall>(MemberList.None)
    .ForMember(d => d.Id , s => s.MapFrom(des => des.Id))
.ForMember(d => d.MovieTitle , s => s.MapFrom(des => des.Movies.MovieTitle))
.ForMember(d => d.HallNo  , s => s.MapFrom(des => des.Halls.HallNo))
.ForMember(d => d.MovieDateTime  , s => s.MapFrom(des => des.MovieDateTime));
```

```
public YourController(ILogger<YourController> logger,             
             IMapper mapper)
        {
            Logger = logger;            
            Mapper = mapper;            
        }

        public ILogger<YourController> Logger { get; }

        public IMapper Mapper { get; }
```

See if this helps to solve your issue. Please provide the Entities details if you still have issues.

Comment: But, is it still manually mapped? `select new MovieHallDto
                             {
                                 Id = mh.Id,
                                 MovieTitle = m.MovieTitle,
                                 HallNo = h.HallNo,
                                 MovieDateTime = mh.MovieDateTime
                             })`

Comment: Thanks @Karthikk. But there is an error in `var movieHallDto = Mapper.Map<List<MovieHallDto>>(movieHalls);`. Error says `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Mapper.Map<List<MovieHallDto>>(object)'`

Comment: @Steve - Mapper is public property. Use the mapper as shown in the updated answer.